oscilloscope style - loop getFloatTimeDomainData(timeData) in a circle
I'm doing simple audio visualisations in canvas for fun and found getFloatTimeDomainData(timeData) to deliver the nicest results in direct representation. my example includes a horizontal representation, based on timeData, fixed at both ends by a sine overlay. This works nicely - 'string' vibrates in the middle only.
the attempt to present same data in circular form fails in some detail, due to the time based nature of this data. as i draw one data array per frame instead of a continuous line. thus the beginning and end of an 'moment snapshot' array can't align in a circle and two consecutive arrays may be too far apart in time for the latter's start to seemlessly match to previous end - thus instead of a closed and continuous line i get open curve ends in the visualisation (right side of circle). it works otherwise and the flaw is barely visible with frame rate and bincount large enough. i'd like to draw this as continuous line though. ideas?
image shows a low sine and the problem: https://i.imgur.com/1yIDEYp.jpeg
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sound in vis</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {background-color:#000000; color:#333333;
  overflow: hidden;} 
  
  canvas {
    background-color:#000000; 
    position: absolute;   
    display: block;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     //filter: blur(1px); 
     }
     #fps {
      color:#F3F3F3;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="ImprovedNoise.js"></script>
<script src="index_version.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

ImprovedNoise.js

// http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/

var ImprovedNoise = function () {

    var p = [151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,
         23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,
         174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,
         133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,
         89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,
         202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,
         248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,
         178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,
         14,239,107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,138,236,205,
         93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180];

    for (var i=0; i < 256 ; i++) {

        p[256+i] = p[i];

    }

    function fade(t) {

        return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);

    }

    function lerp(t, a, b) {

        return a + t * (b - a);

    }

    function grad(hash, x, y, z) {

        var h = hash & 15;
        var u = h < 8 ? x : y, v = h < 4 ? y : h == 12 || h == 14 ? x : z;
        return ((h&1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h&2) == 0 ? v : -v);

    }

    return {

        noise: function (x, y, z) {

            var floorX = ~~x, floorY = ~~y, floorZ = ~~z;

            var X = floorX & 255, Y = floorY & 255, Z = floorZ & 255;

            x -= floorX;
            y -= floorY;
            z -= floorZ;

            var xMinus1 = x -1, yMinus1 = y - 1, zMinus1 = z - 1;

            var u = fade(x), v = fade(y), w = fade(z);

            var A = p[X]+Y, AA = p[A]+Z, AB = p[A+1]+Z, B = p[X+1]+Y, BA = p[B]+Z, BB = p[B+1]+Z;

            return lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA], x, y, z), 
                            grad(p[BA], xMinus1, y, z)),
                        lerp(u, grad(p[AB], x, yMinus1, z),
                            grad(p[BB], xMinus1, yMinus1, z))),
                    lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x, y, zMinus1),
                            grad(p[BA+1], xMinus1, y, z-1)),
                        lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x, yMinus1, zMinus1),
                            grad(p[BB+1], xMinus1, yMinus1, zMinus1))));

        }
    }
}

index_version.js

const myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");


var W           = myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var Wcenter = W/2;
var H           = myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var Hcenter = H/2;
var bpmAdd  = H/40;
var mathPI  = Math.PI;
var mathPIhalf = Math.PI/2;
var mathPI2 = Math.PI*2;
var bstate  = true; //toggle bool stop start animation
var fps, fpsInterval, startTime, now, then, elapsed;
fps = 30;
fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;

then = window.performance.now();
startTime = then;

let freqs;
let timeData;

var bumpcount=0;

function round(int){return Math.round(int);}
function map(value, istart, istop, ostart, ostop){
  return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart));
}
function percOfRange(value, range, maxval){
    return((value<range) ? Math.round(value*100/range)/100 : maxval);
}
function sin(e){return Math.sin(e);}
function cos(e){return Math.cos(e);}

function degrees_to_radians(degrees){  return degrees * Math.PI;}
function radians_to_degrees(radians){  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;};

function ease(p, g){
  if (p < 0.5)
    return 0.5 * Math.pow(2*p, g);
  else
    return 1 - 0.5 * Math.pow(2*(1 - p), g);} 

let elapsedAV       = [];
var elapsedMean = 0;
var noisePos = 0;
var perlin = new ImprovedNoise();

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
  devices.forEach((d, i) => console.log(d.kind, d.label, i));
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ audio: {deviceId: devices[2].deviceId}})
    .then(stream => {
      const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
      const analyser = context.createAnalyser();
      analyser.maxDecibels = -2;
      analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.6;

      const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      source.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(context.destination);
      analyser.fftSize = 1024;

      const bufferlength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
      freqs = new Uint8Array(bufferlength);
      const tDataLength = 128;
      //timeData = new Uint8Array(bufferlength);
      timeData = new Float32Array(bufferlength);
      var cons = 0;
      var colcount = 0;


      function countcol(inc, max){
        (colcount>max) ? colcount = 0 : colcount +=inc;
        return(colcount);
      }      
                 
      let bars                          = 11;
            let bump                            = 0;
            
      function draw(){
        
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqs);
        //analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeData);
        analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData(timeData);
        //analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(freqs);
        const maxvalT                   = Math.max(...timeData);
            const minvalT                   = Math.min(...timeData);
            //console.log(maxvalT + ", " + minvalT);
       
        var average                 = 0;        
        var fLength                 = analyser.fftSize/2; //128,256,512,1024
        

        // Draw bars
        const deltabar              = round(fLength / bars);
        const maxval                    = Math.max(...freqs);
        const minval                    = Math.min(...freqs);
        const indexmax          = freqs.indexOf(maxval);
        const indexmin          = freqs.indexOf(minval);
        const range                 = maxval - minval;
        const rangefactor   = 360 / range * 0.1;
        const radians           = mathPI2 / bars;// * rangefactor;        
        var freqsum                 = 0;
        var freqsumAverage  = 0;
        var fcount                  = 0;
        var fval                        = 1;
        var colArr                      = [];

        for (var i=1; i<5; i++){
          fval = freqs[i];          
          fcount ++;
          freqsum+=fval;
        }
        
        freqsumAverage = round(map( freqsum / fcount,0,256,0,1)*1000)/1000;
        //console.log(freqsumAverage + ", elapsed: " + round(elapsed));

        for (var c=fcount; c<fLength;c++){
            fval = freqs[c];
          freqsum+=fval;
        }        
        let median = round(freqsum / fLength);
                average     = map(median,0,128,0,1);                
        noisePos += 0.01+(average/1000);
        var noiseVal = perlin.noise(noisePos, 0, 0)+0.5;//Math.abs()
        colcount    = round(map(noiseVal,0,1,0,360))%360;
                //console.log(colcount);

          let hue         = colcount;
          let saturation    = (freqsumAverage*30)+70;
          let lum               = (freqsumAverage*20)+30;      
          let alpha             = (freqsumAverage*0.5)+0.5;

                    colArr[0]      = "hsla(" +  hue %360 + ", " + saturation  + "% ," + lum + "%, " + (alpha) + ")";
          colArr[1]      = "hsla(" +  (hue+60 %360) + ", " + saturation  + "% ," + lum + "%, " + (alpha) + ")";
          colArr[2]      = "hsla(" +  (hue+120 %360) + ", " + saturation  + "% ," + lum + "%, " + (alpha) + ")";
          colArr[3]      = "hsla(" +  (hue+180 %360) + ", " + saturation  + "% ," + lum + "%, " + (alpha) + ")";
          colArr[4]      = "hsla(" +  (hue+240 %360) + ", " + saturation  + "% ," + lum + "%, " + (alpha) + ")";

                
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //timedata vis - oscillo style

                //************************************************************************
            //make timedata a circle    
            
            //var cbars     = round(map(sin(now)*freqsumAverage,-1,1,0,bufferlength*freqsumAverage));
            var cbars       = bufferlength;
            let slice   = mathPI2 / cbars;
            var segm        = round(bufferlength/cbars);
                let angle   = slice;
                
                ctx.lineCap = "round";
                var Csize   = 10;

                var curveStartx,curveStarty,vstart; 
                
                ctx.strokeStyle=colArr[3];
                ctx.beginPath();
                
            for(var i = 0; i <= cbars; i++){                    

                var thistimedata = timeData[segm*i];
                    const v = map(thistimedata,-1,1,0,Csize);               
                var cx  = cos(angle)*60;
                var cy  = sin(angle)*60;
                
                var cx2 = cx*v+Wcenter;
                var cy2 = cy*v+Hcenter;

                ctx.lineWidth = v%4;                
                ctx.lineTo(cx2, cy2);
                    
                if(i==0){ curveStartx = cx2/v;curveStarty = cy2/v;vstart=v;}
                angle += slice;
                }
                ctx.lineTo(curveStartx*vstart, curveStarty*vstart);
                ctx.stroke();
                

        //************************************************************************
            //make timedata a horizontal wave - fixed at both ends

                ctx.strokeStyle = colArr[0];
            ctx.beginPath();
            var datarange = bufferlength/2;
            const sliceWidth = W / datarange;
            let x = 0;
            
            //increment to limit signal to 0 at screen borders
                var incr = mathPIhalf/(datarange/2);

                timeData.forEach((data, i) => {

                    //multiply sin of predefined increment with data so as to limit ends of array to 0
                const v = map(sin(incr*i)*data,-1,1,0,1);
                const y = v*H;
                ctx.lineWidth = v*2; 
                if (i === 0) {
                ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                } else {
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                }
                x += sliceWidth;
            });             
            ctx.stroke();

            //************************************************************************
            //end timedata to horizontal string
            
      }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ///end function draw()

      function loop(){
        if(bstate === true ){

            var clearCounter = 0;
            now = performance.now();
            elapsed = round(now - then);
            elapsedAV.push(elapsed);
            
            if( sin(now)>0.5){              
                clear();
            }

            if(elapsedAV.length > 32){              
                        elapsedAV.shift();
                        elapsedMean = round(elapsedAV.reduce((a,b) => a + b)/elapsedAV.length);                     
                        //fps = elapsedMean;
            } 
                    //console.log(elapsed + ", " + elapsedMean);

            if (elapsed >= fpsInterval) {
                
                        //fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;                     
                        bpmAdd  = H/elapsedMean;
            draw();
            then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
            }
            myReq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }
        
      }     
      
      function clear(){
                        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                ctx.fillStyle = "hsla(0, 0% , 0%, 0.1)";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';               
      }

      function toggle(){
        cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
        bstate = !bstate;
        myReq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);       
      } 

      window.addEventListener( 'resize',  function(){
            cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
          W = myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
          H = myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
          myReq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      });

      window.addEventListener( 'click', toggle);
      myReq = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   });
});

..for test route sound to browser via virtual cable and allow window to use audio sources. input is fixed to sources[2] (after mic) in example.
Desired result is a continuous line representation of FloatTimeData, aka analog input to oscilloscope in xy mode.
edit: this post deals with the problem too web audio analyser's getFloatTimeDomainData buffer offset wrt buffers at other times and wrt buffer of 'complete file'

workaround: if i adjust the angle of display to account for time elapsed since last frame , (not use the full 360° for display) i do get symmetrical and harmonious lissajol patterns, with a small wedge of missing data. tested with low sine. as i understand, timedata is picked at points in time that are distanced by frame rate or timer function and can't be continuous this way. for my visualisation purposes it is sufficient to adjust for the lack of data. results are more regular now and much nicer. the post i linked helped me, because i think it wrongly assumes timedata to overlap.
